# Try to return JSON value from function it print but not return from function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm try to return JSON so I can store the return value in to variable but JSON variable gets print but not return the value.
Or there is other way to I can fetch these variable to other function except global variable.

## CODE

```
import json
import urllib.request

class Weather:
    def set_api(self):
        url =   'http://api.wunderground.com/api/8187218c2aca04ca/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json'
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        json_string = f.read()
        parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
        location = parsed_json['location']['city']
        temp_c = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_c']
        print (location, temp_c)                             #WORKING
        return location,temp_c                               #NOT WORKING
        f.close()

myweather = Weather()
myweather.set_api()
```

## OUTPUT

```
Cedar Rapids 10.2 #print output
```

Comment: Try to use `location, temp_c = myweather.set_api()`

Comment: Also, `f.close()` is never executed. You should be using `with`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed code it was returning but it has save in variable and then need to print or pass to other function.
Actually I wanted whole JSON so as per need I was fetching required fields from list dictionary.

## CODE

```
import json
import urllib.request

class Weather:
    def set_api(self):
        url =   'http://api.wunderground.com/api/8187218c2aca04ca/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json'
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        json_string = f.read()
        parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
        return parsed_json                               
        f.close()

myweather = Weather()
yoweather = myweather.set_api()
print(yoweather['location']['city'],yoweather['current_observation']['temp_c'])
```

## OUTPUT

```
Cedar Rapids 10.0
```